# Error reporting saas for transpiled nodejs app

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, babeljs, source-maps

I'm looking for a SaaS like https://airbrake.io/ or https://sentry.io/ that supports transpiled code. We are using Typescript in one app and Babel in another one. The problem we have is that the errors we get from this tools is the compiled javascript and not the source code stack trace. From what I understand, this tools works with sourcemaps but only for client side javascript, not server side.

Anyone knows a SaaS that natively supports nodejs source maps ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We ended up using https://sentry.io that recently added support for source maps for server side code.